# more javascript run-ins

Tags: javascript

I have a list of checkboxes. Each have a class, either East or West. I have 2 links currently, Select All, Select None. I'm making 2 new links, Select East, Select West. I'm using the following javascript to select the checkboxes by class:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function checkAll(theForm, cName, status) {
        for (i=0,n=theForm.elements.length;i<n;i++)
          if (theForm.elements[i].className.indexOf(cName) !=-1) {
            theForm.elements[i].checked = status;
          }
        }

</script>
```

Here is a copy of the onClick:

```
<a href="" onclick="$('sites').select('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(e){if(!e.checked)e.click();}); return false;">Select All</a> | 
<a href="" onclick="$('sites').select('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(e){if(e.checked)e.click();}); return false;">Select None</a> | 
<a href="" onclick="checkAll(document.getElementById('selectForm'), 'East', this.checked);">East</a> | 
<a href="" onclick="checkAll(document.getElementById('selectForm'), 'West', this.checked);">West</a>
```

The Javascript is not working and reloads my page after clicking my new links. Help please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing the `return false` from your East & West links, thus the reload. Also I don't think you should be passing the checked status of the checkbox into the function. I think your `if` should be something like

```
if (theForm.elements[i].className.indexOf(cName) !=-1) {
  // select the ones that are in the class
  theForm.elements[i].checked = true;
}
else {
  // deselect the ones that are not in the class
  theForm.elements[i].checked = false;
}
```

** UPDATE: **

In that case you would want to pass in the state of the checkboxes in. You will essentially need to change the behaviour so that each link becomes a toggle. So you don't do anything to the other classes, and you invert the status of the class the user clicked on.

```
if (theForm.elements[i].className.indexOf(cName) !=-1) {
  // toggle the checked status of the current class of checkboxes
  theForm.elements[i].checked = !state;
}
```

Comment: Matti, I have added 3 2 more links. Select All, Select None, Select East, Select West, Select State, Select RDA. Each have their own classes I'm selecting. What if I want to select East AND RDA together? Currently using your code If I select East it selects all East and deselects everything. So when I click RDA, it erases all my East checks and only selects classes RDA....In essence, how to select multiple options without them overwriting each other?

Comment: @Travis: you'll want to make the function into a toggle. See update above.

Comment: Hey Matti, I've modified it, but it's once again just reloading my page. Even though I have return false; at the end of my onclick. Any idea?

Comment: How about trying what bluefoot suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace

```
onclick="checkAll..."
```

to

```
onclick="return checkAll..."
```

And your `checkAll` function must return `false`

Is just another way to do it.